# Why incremental in gradle dependency is bad?

Tags: android, gradle

I've heard that using incremental dependency in Gradle is bad.
like this

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
}
```

Is that so? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two primary issues with using wildcard dependency versions:

First, you lose control over when you update. This means that you could potentially get a bad version of the library, or pull down a good version that introduces breaking changes before you are ready to address those changes.

Second, your builds are no longer reproducible. If in a few months you decide you need to build the exact version of the app that you had on May 28th, 2015, you will find that task much more difficult because you don't know what the precise version of the library you were using on that date. If you simply check out the code from that date, you are receiving whatever version is *currently* the latest instead of what the latest version was on that date.